# express multer uploaded files url

Tags: node.js, express, multer

probably a stupid question but maybe someone here could help me.

after uploading files with `multer` and express, what would be the url of the uploaded files to `uploads/`?

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'uploads/')
    }
});
```

if it's an image, how can i link to it like:
`http://localhost:3000/uploads/image.jpg`?

should i place the uploaded files in the public directory?

thanks

Comment: managed to solve this by adding a public express directory with 'app.use', although i'm not sure what will happen if i have matching locations on both public directories. like 'public/img' and 'uploads/img'

Answer (score 2):

This is how I setup Multer for `expressjs`. First you have to overwrite the renaming function if you want to keep the original filename. Then you have to move the uploads folder to the public folder.

```
// this uploads a single input[file] field called 'image'
var express = require('express'),
    multer = require('multer'),
    upload = multer({
        storage: multer.diskStorage({
            destination: 'public/images/uploads/',
            filename: function(req, file, cb) {
                // this overwrites the default multer renaming callback
                // and simply saves the file as it is
                cb(null, file.originalname)
            }
        })
    }),
    router = express.Router()

// add route
router.post('/uploadimage', upload.single('image'), function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.file) return next(new Error('Select a file!'))
    // be careful here as the upload path has 'public' at the start 
    // which is the static mounted directory so doesn't show
    // here the path is build manually
    var imagePath = '/images/uploads/' + req.file.filename;
    res.end('<img src=" + imagePath + " />')        
})
```

additionally you can keep the default upload path as `/uploads` and mount it as a static folder

```
  // Mount uploads
  app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./uploads')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make static teh diskstoarge location in your case 'uploads' folder should be  static

```js
app.use(express.static('uploads'));
```

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html